# I hide the checkbox from the ExpandableListView but expandableListview doesn't work properly

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview

> I created `ExpandableListView` with following `getView` method

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                     View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
Group_Items gr = (Group_Items) getGroup(groupPosition);
long group_id = getGroupId(groupPosition);

if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.expandable_group_items, null);

    // adding onClick listener on CheckBox for the very first time
    chk=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk);
    chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = (int) v.getTag();
            mSelections.put(position, !mSelections.get(position, false));
            ((CheckBox)v).setChecked(mSelections.get(position, false));
        }
    });
}

TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText(gr.getName());
CheckBox chk=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk);
chk.setTag(groupPosition);
// reassigning checkbox to its ticked state
chk.setChecked(mSelections.get(groupPosition, false));
```

`if(groupPosition==2)
     {
      ch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
    return convertView;
}`

*I uses above `if(groupPosition==2)` method to hide `CheckBox` of third item from `ExpandablelistView` but..*

> I faces another problem when I expand `First` or `Second` Item then `CheckBoxes` position is automatically changed

so guys I am confused now How to handle this error

[Here is my app](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4WLNcB0KW3HV0FvOWtxdXlhcW8/view?usp=sharing) 
you can check it and please help me

Comment: You have to handle the else condition in your code  if(groupPosition==2)
     {
      ch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
    return convertView;
}else{     {
      ch.setVisibility(View.VISIBILE);
      }
    return convertView;
}

Comment: I will check your answer

Answer (score 0):

> Guys Here I tried following answer it worked for me

```
 if(groupPosition==2) {
        chk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return convertView;
    }
    else {
        chk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return convertView;
    }
```